# Using ifelse to change column names in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to create a function that cleans some messy dataframes, and I need to specify the names of the columns according to some inputs using ifelse.

```
  aporte_apv <- c("Fondo", "Serie", "Cantidad.de.Aportes")
  aporte_ffmm <- c("Rut.Cliente", "Cuenta", "Fecha")

colnames(base) <- ifelse(tolower(transaccion)=="apv", aporte_apv, 
                         ifelse(tolower(transaccion)=="ffmm", aporte_ffmm, stop("not valid inputs")))
```

Apparently ifelse can't handle vectors, how can I do this in an elegant way?

Comment: *"Apparently ifelse can't handle vectors"* Nonsense. What makes you believe that's the case? `ifelse` is a vectorised function.

Comment: We will need to know what `base` and `transaccion` look like in order to help you - can you please include workable samples of these objects in an edit?

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, but how can I replace the columns names with it? it only takes the first element. Do you know what I'm doing worng?

Comment: `ifelse` returns a value with the same shape as your (logical) test object. In other words, if your test object has length 1, so has the return object. The answer lies in the structure of `base` and `transaccion`.

Comment: thanks! that's what i needed :)

Comment: Note that you can assign the result inside the `ifelse` and get a vector (see my answer on the post linked)